# std::byte overhead from integer promotion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, integer-promotion, std-byte

Consider an `unsigned char v` that goes through a series of bit-wise operations with the result stored back to `v`. Under the hood, it is integer promoted once, undergoes a series of operations, and the result is truncated and stored back to `v`.

With `std::byte v`, however, for **each and every** operation, the operand is first integer promoted, undergoes the operation, and the (intermediate) result is truncated and stored back to some `std::byte`. That would be many back-and-forth promotion and truncation. This is all conceptual, but would it cause real overhead in practice?

#### Artificial Example

```
// `mask` and `lshf` are of type `unsigned`
unsigned char v = ...;
v = (v & mask) << lshf; // one promotion at `&` and one truncation at `=`
```

```
// `mask` and `lshf` are of type `std::byte` and `unsigned`
std::byte v = ...;
v = (v & mask) << lshf;

// It would be like
// byte(unsigned(byte(unsigned(v) & unsigned(mask))) << lshf)
```

#### Real-Case Example

Let's say we want to zero out the leading 3 bits of a byte.

```
unsigned char v = ...;
v = (v << 3 & 0xff) >> 3;
```

vs.

```
std::byte v = ...;
v = v << 3 >> 3;
```

Comment: can you show an example where the `unsigned char` is promoted once but the `std::byte` on every operation?

Comment: You'd need to look at the optimized (`-O3`) assembly, or profile.  Probably does not have any appreciable overhead... but to be sure:  **profile**.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If you do `(var << 3) >> 2` that has one promotion if `var` is a `unsigned char`  if it is a `std::byte` it has to convert to an `unsigned int` and back to a `std::byte` for each operation.

Comment: Anecdotally, I'd say only in unoptimized builds. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/E6qoxb3Kj vs. https://godbolt.org/z/scjse5Mxj